# Can I pass a value and submit a form from the same hyperlink?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am trying to create a list of links that would make up the elements of a form (will be used as a search feature).

Basically, each link in the list represents a search category, so as users click on a link, their search results will be filtered.

I would need a category value to be able to be passed whenever someone clicks on one of those category links, and also have each link act as the form submit as well. Is that possible?

(There may be easier ways to accomplish this, however with the CMS and search module I'm using, this will have to do.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to pass values via both POST and GET? I am not sure that that would work. Why not just used hidden form fields? In your form, add a number of `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">` and each one of them will be passed back to the server along with all the regular form fields.

Note: Hidden form fields can be read and edited by a sufficiently tech savy user (it is not too hard), but this would be the case with any variables that you are passing between the server and client, even cookies.

Comment: The search itself will be using POST only. Could I dynamically change the hidden field's value based on the click of a link as the form is submitted?

Comment: @Kurt You could, with JavaScript. It is just changing the value of the field. You favorite JS library will have a way to do it. For example, in JQuery, you can use [.val(value)](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Answer (score 0):

If you give the links an internal `data-category` attribute like this:

```
<a href="#" data-category="foo">Foo</a>
```

then you can do with jQuery:

```
$('a[data-category]').click(function() {
    filterResults($(this).data('category')); // call the function that filters
                                             // results according to chosen
                                             // category
    $('#theform').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of...

```
<a href="#" class="category">Puma</a>
```

and use the a script like...

```
$('a.category').click(function(e) { 
  $('#someForm input[name=category]').val( $(this).text() ); 
  $('#someForm').submit(); 
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you intend to do with the data from the link, or even which part of it you need, but I hope this helps.

```
<form name="myForm">
 <a href="#" onClick="submitMyForm(this);">link</a>
</form>

<script>
 function submitMyForm(link){
   var mylinkText = link.text;
   var myLinkHref = link.href;
   document.myForm.submit();
 }
</script>
```

If you need the link clicked to come across as part of your form data, perhaps you could put it in a hidden field on the form... something like:

```
document.myForm.myHiddenLinkField.value = mylinkText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the jQuery tag has been removed, here's an example of doing this form submit with pure javascript:

http://www.neubreed.com.au/blog/2010/07/submit_form_anchor_tag_using_javascript_and_supply_action

You can create an extra hidden input like in the example to set your category:

```
function submitForm(id, category){
  var myform = document.getElementById(id);

  if (document.createElement) {
    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = 'category';
    input.value = category;
    myform.appendChild(input);
  }
  myform.submit();
  return false;
}
```

Then, in your form:

```
<a href="somewhere" onclick="submitForm('formid', document.getElementById('category').value);">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a hidden field.

```
<form id="cuteform" action="thedestiny.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="filter"/>
</form>
<a onclick="javascript:linkaction(this);" id="linkA">blablabla</a>
<a onclick="javascript:linkaction(this);" id="linkB">blablabla</a>

<script>
function linkaction(link) {
    // get the field
    var f = document.getElementById("filter");

    // then you could use some of the link element's property like id or innerHTML
    f.value = link.id;
    // or you could use a switch structure
    switch (link.id) {
        case "linkA": f.value = "the huge filter string"; break;
        case "linkB": f.value = "another stuff"; break;
    }

    // submit the form
    document.getElementById("cuteform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: The prefix `javascript:` isn't necessary. Any command(s) inside the `onclick` is/are treated as javascript automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to style an actual form button as a link using CSS.

So essentially for each "link":

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="form-link">
</form>
```

For the CSS (off the top of my head) something like this should do it:

```
.form-link {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #00f;
}
```

That way it isn't dependent on JavaScript to work and users without it will still be able to make use of your site. Additionally, inline event handlers (onclick) etc shouldn't be used as they mix semantics with behaviour. If the functionality isn't core to the experience and (perhaps therefore doesn't require a base non-JavaScript version) then write the links into the page with JavaScript from an external JavaScript include. You won't then have a bunch of dead links in the page for users that visit your site with JavaScript disabled or from a non-JavaScript capable device.

Comment: Of course I should have mentioned that you'll need to add whatever hidden fields are necessary to each form to pass the data that's relevant to the backend.